# How to store scraped links in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I did a lot of searches on the web but I couldn't find anything related or maybe it has to do with the wording used.

Basically, I would like to write a spider that would able to save the scraped links and to check if some other links have been already scraped. Is there any build in function in scrapy to do so?

Many thanks

Comment: I also had the same question. I fixed it by preparing a log. I wrote all URLs after parse done with their referer and I checked on start_urls as property before scrape start. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own method for this purpose. I have written in my project and you can take reference from this. A dictionary called already_parsed_urls and for every callback, I am updating this dictionary.

You can look at the below code snippet and take reference.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = []
    web_url = ''
    start_urls = ['']
    counter = 0
    already_parsed_urls = {}
    
    wait_time = 3
    timeout = '90'

    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(start_url, callback=self.parse_courses,
                                args={'wait': self.wait_time, 'timeout': self.timeout})

    def parse_courses(self, response):
        course_urls = []

        yield SplashRequest(course_urls[0], callback=self.parse_items, args={'wait': self.wait_time})

    def parse_items(self, response):

        if not self.already_parsed_urls.get(response.url):
            
            # Get Program URL
            program_url = response.url

            self.already_parsed_urls[response.url] = 1
            
        else:
            return {}
```